# Howto to configure TCA settings and save them globaly

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-tca

I'm configuring a new website with TYPO3 v. 9.5.

I would like to configure TCA settings to make it possible to force editors to fill fields in content elements like media or news.
In former times I was able to put this settings into a file typo3conf/extTables.php.

In my investigations I found, that I have to put configurations into a directory Configuration/TCA/Overrides of an extension.
I tested it with the extension tx_news like this:

I put this code in a file called test.php as a test and example.

This code forces the editor to always enter an archive date.

This works for me, but after an extension update, this code might be lost and I cannot configure the fields of core extensions for example to force an editor to always enter a title of a content element.

My question is, how can I store this configurations update save within the configuration environment?

Thank you in advance,

Ralf

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your modifications you need to consider some aspects:

1. always use a filename according to the table your modifications belong.
   so for the news records it should be: `Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tx_news_domain_model_news.php`
2. make sure your modifications are loaded after the first initial configuration: make a dependency to the original extension.